# Conditionally instantiate a template at run-time

Tags: c++, templates, smart-pointers

I have a template class

```
template <class T> 
class myClass
{
    public:
        /* functions */
    private:
        typename T::Indices myIndices;  
};
```

Now in my main code I want to instantiate the template class depending on a condition. Like :

```
myFunc( int operation)
{
    switch (operation) {
        case 0:
            // Instantiate myClass with <A> 
            auto_ptr < myClass <A> > ptr = new myClass<A> ();
        case 1:
            // Instantiate myClass with <B> 
            auto_ptr < myClass <B> > ptr = new myClass<B> ();
        case 2:
            // Instantiate myClass with <C> 
        ....
    }
    // Use ptr here..
}
```

Now the problem with this approach is that the `auto_ptr<>` will die at the end of `switch{}`.
And I can't declare it at the beginning of the function, because I don't know the type that will be instantiated before-hand.

I know I'm trying to achieve a run-time thing at compile-time (using template), but still wanted to know if there is some better way to do this.

Comment: You appear to have a terminology problem. You _instantiate_ a class template to create a class. You can subsequently create objects of that type. In the exampel given, you want to **instantiate** `myClass` **twice**, with arguments A and B, but **create one** object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a base class

```
class Base {     
  protected:
      virtual ~Base() {}
      //... functions
};

template <class T> class myClass : Base { 
  //...
};

myFunc( int operation){ 
   shared_ptr < Base >  ptr;

   switch (operation) {        
     case 0:            
          // Instantiate myClass with <A>             
          ptr.reset ( new myClass<A> () );        
     case 1:            
          // Instantiate myClass with <B>             
          ptr.reset ( new myClass<B> () ) ;        
      case 2:            
           // Instantiate myClass with <C>         ....    
     }    
     // Use ptr here..
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could introduce a common base to `myClass` and use that as the parameter to `auto_ptr`. Just don't forget to declare that common base's destructor virtual.

Answer (score 2):

[Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/variant.html) should do the trick.

```
myFunc( int operation)
{
    boost::variant< myclass<A>, myclass<B> > obj;
    switch (operation) {
        case 0:
            // Instantiate myClass with <A> 
            obj = myClass<A> ();
        case 1:
            // Instantiate myClass with <B> 
            obj = myClass<B> ();
        case 2:
            // Instantiate myClass with <C> 
        ....
    }
    // Use object here..
}
```

Using the object is a little different because the type is dynamically determined.  The apply_visitor technique is definitely the way to go; see the [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html) for how to use it.

Comment: The issue here is the "un-boxing" required to use the classes in the variant I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a level of indirection to get what you want.  You can avoid a base class with virtual methods and doing any other special stuff.

For example:

```
template <class T> 
class MyClass
{
    public:
        /* functions */
    private:
        typename T::Indices myIndices;  
};

template<typename T>
static void doit()
{
    MyClass<T> t;
    // Use t here.
}

void myfunc(int op)
{
    switch (op) {
        case 0: return doit<A>();
        case 1: return doit<B>();
        // ...
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

low tech solution.  use a regular pointer with the scope you want.