# Assigning datatype for variables dynamically in CPP

Tags: c++

I have a class called `Matrix`, in that there are two variables that I want to define `rows` and `columns`.

**Problem:**
In the constructor of the class I want to assign the values as well as the data types of the rows and columns dynamically.

Is there any way to do this in c++?

**Example:**
In instance `M1` of Matrix class, the datatypes for rows and columns are set as `long long int`, and in instance `M2` of Matrix class, the datatypes are `int`.

Comment: Are you talking about a template `Matrix`? Note that templates need to be expanded at compile time.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ actually im new in cpp, so not so sure about that

Comment: This question is unfortunately a bit vague. Could you elaborate and provide some example code of what you're trying to achieve, such as what the `Matrix` should look like when it's being used? Generally, all types are fixed at compile time in C++. You cannot (conveniently) switch between using `int` and `long long` at runtime.

Comment: @AmeyMeher since you're new to C++, you should be advised that C++ is a very complicated language. There are lots of ways to technically achieve what you're asking, and there are many more ways to do it very wrongly, and it often takes an expert to tell the difference. While you're learning, you should get yourself a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read it carefully.

Comment: @alterigel consider any class, just that the data types of the variables are assigned at run-time. Im not switching between two different datatypes at runtime, but just assigning it at runtime.

Comment: @AmeyMeher exactly thats why you should follow the book-advice. you most likeley do not really need the types at runtime to solve your problem.

Comment: @skeller ok, I'll check it out once!

Comment: C++ really, *really* needs to know the exact characteristics of something before it starts compiling code, which means it needs a concrete type. Until C++ has [generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming) support this requires templates, or a more C++ flavored approach that might be different than you're thinking initially.

Comment: @AmeyMeher Unfortunately I haven't been able to find some good canonical Q&A's  for your question quickly. Though these links I've posted in my answer should be useful to solve the problem to some degree.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yup onto it! Thanks for the links! Got an idea atleast about how to go about the problem

Comment: @AmeyMeher It would be a good idea to [edit] your question and flesh out more what you want to achieve (at least with pseudo code). This could be a good starting pointe for a canonical Q&A regarding the problem at hand.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yup, Would work on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the constructor of the class I want to assign the values as well as the data types of the rows and columns dynamically. Is there any way to do this in c++?

In short: You cannot using the current standard (as of c++-17).

Datatypes need to be resolved at compile time. In c++ we use template classes to have generic data types used in classes. Though, these still have to be resolved at compile time.

There are a number of tricks you can use, to select from those compile time generated types at compile time at runtime anyways.

Related Q&A providing workarounds:

- [Choosing a template instantiation at runtime though switch in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9320125/1413395)
- [Instantiate a template class at run time in terms of different types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36215719/1413395)
- [Conditionally instantiate a template at run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807360/conditionally-instantiate-a-template-at-run-time)
- [Choose template based on run-time string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644146/choose-template-based-on-run-time-string-in-c)
- [Instantiating class with template parameter at runtime (C++)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971948/instantiating-class-with-template-parameter-at-runtime-c)
- [Dynamic Template Instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784898/dynamic-template-instantiation)

There are probably more ...